# How to display only the data which button was clicked ?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I was working on a Bakery Sales System project.
I separate the order page and payment page into two frame.
I want to display the data behind the button in the Payment frame from the Order frame only when the button is clicked.

Is there a way of doing it?

Here is my code for Order Page:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 
class Bun extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 String decimal = "#.##";
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(decimal);
 public final String [] bname = new String [] {"Tuna Sandwich","Garlic Bread","Redbean Bun","Sausage Bun","Chicken Burger","Ham Sandwich","Egg Mayo Bun","Chocolate Bread","Potato Bun"};
 public final double [] bprice = new double [] {1.20, 2, 1.50, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1.50, 1.20};
 public final double [] bsub = new double [] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
 public double bsubtotal=0;

public Bun() {
    initComponents();
}

private void BtnTunaSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    BtnTunaSandwich.setText(bname[1]+" - RM "+bprice[1]);
}                                               

private void BtnGarlicBreadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    BtnGarlicBread.setText(bname[2]+" - RM "+bprice[2]);
}                                              

private void BtnRedbeanBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    BtnRedbeanBun.setText(bname[3]+" - RM "+bprice[3]);
}                                             

private void BtnSausageBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    BtnSausageBun.setText(bname[4]+" - RM "+bprice[4]);
}                                             

private void BtnChickenBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    BtnChickenBurger.setText(bname[5]+" - RM "+bprice[5]);
}                                                

private void BtnHamSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    BtnHamSandwich.setText(bname[6]+" - RM "+bprice[6]);
}                                              

private void BtnEggMayoBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    BtnEggMayoBun.setText(bname[7]+" - RM "+bprice[7]);
}                                             

private void BtnChocolateBreadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    BtnChocolateBread.setText(bname[8]+" - RM "+bprice[8]);
}                                                 

private void BtnPotatoBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    BtnPotatoBun.setText(bname[9]+" - RM "+bprice[9]);
}                                            

private void numTunaSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    bsub[1] = Integer.parseInt(numTunaSandwich.getText())*bprice[1];
}                                               

private void numGarlicBreadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    bsub[2] = Integer.parseInt(numGarlicBread.getText())*bprice[2];
}                                              

private void numRedbeanBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    bsub[3] = Integer.parseInt(numRedbeanBun.getText())*bprice[3];
}                                             

private void numSausageBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    bsub[4] = Integer.parseInt(numSausageBun.getText())*bprice[4];
}                                             

private void numChickenBurgerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    bsub[5] = Integer.parseInt(numChickenBurger.getText())*bprice[5];
}                                                

private void numHamSandwichActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    bsub[6] = Integer.parseInt(numHamSandwich.getText())*bprice[6];
}                                              

private void numEggMayoBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    bsub[7] = Integer.parseInt(numEggMayoBun.getText())*bprice[7];
}                                             

private void numChocolateBreadActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
    bsub[8] = Integer.parseInt(numChocolateBread.getText())*bprice[8];
}                                                 

private void numPotatoBunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    bsub[9] = Integer.parseInt(numPotatoBun.getText())*bprice[9];
}                                            

public void Calculatetotalb(){
    for(double i : bsub){
        bsubtotal += i;
    }
}
```

I haven't write anything yet in the Payment frame.
But here is my order frame looks like:

[image: Order Frame]

And here is my payment frame looks like :

[image: Payment frame]

I want to display the data into that Jlist. 
Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: so you need to pass data  from one frame to another

Comment: Yes basically is that one, I went through online for all information, but did not worked for this as I only want display the data that the button was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well transferring data from one frame to another is nothing but exchanging data between objects. first thing you need to do is implement a 
method inside PaymentFrame which will accept data and change the list

```
class PaymentFrame{

public void setData(String list){
//get the list from the method and update the jlist
jlist.add(list);
}

}
```

and the next step is to call this method from another class inyour case Orderframe

```
class orderFrame{
paymentframe pay; 
public void sendData(String data){
if(pay==null){
pay = new paymentframe();
 }    
pay.setdata(data);
pay.setvisible(true);
}

}
```

here is an example of doing what you have asked bt if you have already opened a PaymentFrame in your project you should access the same object from the order frame.

Comment: Uh, what exactly do I need to write inside the setData method ?

Comment: that was just an example make the method argument to whatever datatype you like and set the data to `jList1.add(data); `

Comment: So I have to write whatever I want to display inside the pay.setdata ("Here?") , but I want to display the particular data when that button was clicked, how to write inside there ? Thanks.

Comment: call sendData() method inside the button pass whatever you want dont ask me what should i write in there what ever you will write in there will be displayed on the jlist